# How Can I Access the Brown Corpus in Java (aka outside of NLTK)

Tags: java, nlp, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

I'm trying to write a program that makes use of natural language parts-of-speech in Java. I've been searching on Google and haven't found the entire Brown Corpus (or another corpus of tagged words). I keep finding NLTK information, which I'm not interested in. I want to be able to load data into a Java program and sum up occurrences of words (and what % likelihood they are to be what part-of-speech).

I **do not** want to use a Java library like the Stanford one, I want to play with the corpus data myself.

Comment: Why are you not interested in NLTK? They have by-far the best coverage of NLP datasets API packed into one library. You don't need to code much, to get what you need in python and in java you get into a heck load of lines, http://pastebin.com/7U9GRpNN. My suggestion, use NLTK process the corpus, output into a text file and read it =) Also see https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a link to the download page for the Brown Corpus: http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/

All the files are zip files.  The data format is described on the [Brown Corpus Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus).  I dunno what else to say.  From there things should be obvious.

EDIT: if you want original source data, I think there's some corpuses out there that have their data.  However usually the point is to let someone else do the sampling.  Also, note this from the the Wikipedia entry: "Each sample began at a random sentence-boundary in the article or other unit chosen, and continued up to the first sentence boundary after 2,000 words."  So the data for the Brown Corpus is essentially randomized.  Even if you had the original texts you might not be able to guess where they sampled.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was hoping/expecting to be able to download the training data from a .edu or something.

Answer (score 4):

Data is data. The NLTK data is not in an obscure, encrypted, or difficult format. Just write java code to read it. You might find a shortcut in WEKA, or you might not.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't there a way to get it from the 'original' source?

Comment: That would be an off-topic question here, but it looks to me as if NLTK _is_ the official distribution, period.

Comment: Just because Wikipedia links to the NLTK's site doesn't mean there's anything "official" about it. The NLTK folks have no connection to Francis & Kucera, its creators. (But since redistribution is freely permitted, it's as good a source as any.)

Comment: My remark is not based on Wikipedia, but rather on perusing other lines of research. There's probably a copy at LDC, and perhaps one in Hawaii, but the most formal distribution I could find was NLTK. Is that 'official'? I don't claim to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to mess with the NLTK interface: The Brown corpus has been deposited at the **Internet Archive** (archive.org). On https://archive.org/details/BrownCorpus you'll find a link to a zip archive containing the entire corpus. (Also a torrent link, but it doesn't seem worth the trouble for 3.2 MB.)

Comment: Thanks for posting the link. I looked at the data briefly, and it seems accurate except that it is completely missing the location codes, which identify genres, and sequences numbers for samples, lines, and words.

Comment: It is missing _what_? Category genres are in the file `cats.txt`. For the rest I've no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: You're right, there is a "cats.txt" file (I missed it because alphabetical listing buries it in among the 500 samples, and because it's not mentioned in the readme). The original Brown Corpus attached a location code to every word, telling you which genre, sample, line, and word number it is. The data on archive.org packs the first two into each file's name, and omits the second two. Also, it breaks lines at sentences, which is not where the original BC did. For many things this won't matter; for some things (such as understanding specific location references in publications), it will.